# simple data binding to datagrid not happening

Tags: silverlight-4.0

i have an datagrid i am trying to bind an value to label which is under datatemplate
 but no binding is happening her. ?

```
 <sdk:Label  DataContext="{Binding CompanyName}" Width="50" />
```

i have  an column  which is  above datatemplate there the values are getting binded.

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn  Header="CompanyName" Binding="{Binding CompanyName}"/>
```

but in  controls inside data tempalate values are not getting binded.
 image  field is getting binded with image  source what we have specfied.

what is the issue happening here no data binding taking place . help me  out

thanks in advance 
 prince

Answer (score 0):

the issue  was  the  the option what i was  using for  binding
 for  label  to bind  we have  to use  this property.
Content="{Binding
CompanyName}"

> 